# Using kplotwidget in Qt Creator

Tags: qt4, kde-plasma

How to use Kplotwidget in QtCreator, i added  /use/lib/kde4 and /usr/include/kde4 in .pro, and try to add library like libkde.so, libkdeui.so (from kde4 subfolders) but nothing useful,my build output is "  error while loading shared libraries: libkde.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `libkde.so` includes only KDECore library classes. If you want to use GUI elements from KDE you have to include `libkdeui.so`. Add to your .pro following:

> unix:!macx:!symbian: LIBS += -lkdeui

Comment: same thing I did but it is giving me error like "error while loading shared libraries: libkde.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory " irrespective of whether i am adding libkde.so or not,  more i have to explicitly include #include   "incl/kde4/kplotwidget.h"
     #include "incl/kde4/kplotobject.h"

Comment: Btw. what classes from KDE are you using except the KPlotWidget. Because the KPlotWidget is in libkdeui.so

Comment: in /usr/include/kde4/ i found kplotwidget.h, after including it , compiler not giving error of  kplotwidget.h: No such file or directory

Comment: I have fedora14, how to check kdebase-workspace-dev installation

Comment: I used this command,find /usr/ -type f -name "*kdev*.so*" and i found some result, so i have kdebase-workspace-dev install

Answer (score 0):

solution for Qt Creator 2.4

1. go to .pro file
2. add line:   LIBS+=/usr/lib64/libkdeui.so.5 \
   -L/usr/lib64
3. add line:  INCLUDEPATH+= /usr/include/kde4

Above solution allows to avoid problems with KDE family widgets (e.g. KLed, KColorButton, etc)